# wp_query - sort by custom field of a linked post

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I read a lot about sorting by custom fields but can't find an answer to this problem.

I have 2 post types: Institution and Course.
Institutions have a custom field "area"
Courses have a custom field "inst" which contains the ID of the institution.

Now I have a page that shows courses search results, and I want to sort them by the area of the institution they are linked to.
Custom php sorting after getting the results is not an option since I am using pagination with ajax (and then I can sort only the results of a specific page).

How can I do this sorting inside the WP_Query?

Comment: Please show us your current query.

Comment: Please show the structure of your database (the relevant parts). A useful  way of making a [mcve] for SQL questions is tailoring a toy database in SQLite and using `.dump` from commandline tool. Read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen@Yunnosch
Its Wordpress. The structure of the DB is a row in wp_posts as for each post, and one-to-many relation between wp_posts and wp_postmeta for the custom fields.  
  
For example (Course 1 belongs to Inst A, which is in the North area):  
**wp_posts**  
ID=1, post_type="institution", post_title="Inst A"  
ID=2, post_type="institution", post_title="Inst B"  
ID=3, post_type="course",post_title="Course 1"  
**wp_postmeta**  
post_id=1,meta_name="area", meta_value="North"  
post_id=2,meta_name="area", meta_value="South"  
post_id=3,meta_name="inst", meta_value="1"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it partyle by using this code, and showing all results if this filter was selected... still no way to paginate.

```
if ($orderby_area) { /* Code for sorting by institution area */
    foreach ($query->posts as $program) {
        $program->institution_area = get_post_meta(get_post_meta($program->ID,'institution ',true),'area',true);
        $program->mossad = get_the_title(get_post_meta($program->ID,'institution ',true));
    }
    usort($query->posts, function($a, $b)
    {
        if ($a->inst_area==$b->inst_area)
            return $a->institution >$b->institution ;
        return $a->institution_area>$b->institution_area;
    });
    $programs = array_slice($query->posts,($getpage-1)*20,20);
}
```